# Xamarin ListView space issue when two listview Put in ScrollView. Need a solution.

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a listview. Where I put my two listviews in Scroll view property. My requirement is a single scroll on the page so I am using that.
but however, I face space issue between two listviews.  and also footer of the page.  I already use footer property but it's not working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jikIx.png)

Comment: Try to post more details. What effects you want to achieve? And what effort you have done? From your image we just see that you want to add some spaces between two listviews, Margin may be helpful. Try to post some code.

Answer (score 0):

> Application developers should not nest one ScrollView within another.
>   Additionally, they should refrain from nesting them other elements
>   that can scroll, such as WebView.

Source: [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView?view=xamarin-forms#remarks).

Nested `ScrollViews` are disaster just don't do that.
Which control will get scrolled on a user interaction? It will totally ruin the UX, performance and etc.

The space here is the smallest problem as you understand. You have to rethink your UI. You can replace the `ScrollView` by a single [grouped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#grouping) `ListView` for example.